# Column alias is not working for Group, Where and Having in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, having

I am having the following problem.
I want to execute as sql statement that filters the results with HAVING. However the having is on a column that is calculated from an IF() function inside the select. This way, MySQL server complains that the column inside having clause is unknown!

EX:

```
SELECT col1,col2,IF(expr1,expr2,expr3) AS `wantedColumn`

FROM....

WHERE ...

HAVING LENGTH(`wantedColumn)>0
```

It is as mysql cannot understand that the column returned by the if expression is named wantedColumn... If I use other columns it is working correctly. But I need to filter on that. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by comment from Inanda Menezes @Inanda:

> Look at it: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5294e4/6 , I just removed the backticks
>   from the alias used inside the having and your example worked.
>   According to mysql documentation you don't need to use backticks on
>   identifiers that does not have special words or characters. If you use
>   it, in most of cases, it will not cause your query to fail, but it's
>   not necessary at all to quote normal identifiers with non-standard
>   escape. Anyway, it seems to fail when escaping with backsticks a alias
>   in having clause which uses length function, so just don't escape this
>   one. –  Inanda Menezes

Answer (score 3):

**This is due to mode configurations:**

If your database is using the mode 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', you will not be able to use a column alias in WHERE, GROUP BY or HAVING, it does not work. You have to either repeat the whole expression or use sub query.

In order to know if you are using 'ONLY_FULL GROUP_BY' mode, use the following query:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

If you want to change it to a mode that allows it:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode =STRICT_TRANS_TABLES;
```

To know more about SQL modes: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already tried to repeat he whole expression in a where clause and it works. My problem is not that I cannot use colum alias in general. Because If I use the having with reference to an other column alias it works. I cannot use column alias on the column produced by the if clause.

Comment: Also please note that while the problem exists on mysql 5.5 version tried on an online host, it does not exist on a mysql 5.6 local server. It works as it should and does not complain about an unknown attribute on the 5.6 local server

Comment: In SQLfiddle.com version 5.5.32 (STRICT_TRANS_TABLES  mode) it works.

Comment: As I said, column alias is working in general and also in HAVING clause. What is not working is column alias of a column produced with the IF(expr1,expr2,expr3) statement and then using that column alias in a HAVING. Could you provide a working example in contrast to my example?

Comment: Thank you for your trouble again... To be more precise I was creating some update code for a prestashop module. I have also created an SQL fiddle with the problem showing in order for you to see the exact data... [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5294e4/4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5294e4/4)

Comment: Look at it: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5294e4/6 , I just removed the backticks from the alias used inside the having and your example worked. According to mysql documentation you don't need to use backticks on identifiers that does not have special words or characters. If you use it, in most of cases, it will not cause your query to fail, but it's not necessary at all to quote normal identifiers with non-standard escape. Anyway, it seems to fail when escaping with backsticks a alias in having clause which uses length function, so just don't escape this one.

Comment: I can't believe it was just this... Thank you for your answer. This is the correct solution yes.